# Eclipse Plug-In Error with Authorization

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API and everything **worked fine in an Eclipse stand-alone Java-Project**. Now I wanted to add (the very same) code to my **Eclipse Plug-in. Unfortunately, I now have the problem, that the authentication with the Google API doesn't work properly anymore**. After `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");`  the browser starts the authentication-process where I can click "Authenticate" after that the browser does something I don't know (infinite loading) and stops only if i cancle the programme. In the Eclipse console, I get the following error:

`!MESSAGE While loading class "org.mortbay.jetty.RetryRequest", thread "Thread[349166459@qtp-300209212-1 - Acceptor0 SocketConnector@localhost:18312,5,main]" timed out waiting (5005ms) for thread "Thread[main,6,main]" to finish starting bundle "myproject.version.qualifier [896]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[349166459@qtp-300209212-1 - Acceptor0 SocketConnector@localhost:18312,5,main]" is proceeding but "org.mortbay.jetty.RetryRequest" may not be fully initialized.`

I don't know what this error means and what I can do. Thanks for your help!

casaout

PS: I have the working sample (only in a normal Eclipse project, NOT in an eclipse plug-in project) from [here](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I found a way around this problem (bug?)... I just made a new (fragment) project and made the authorization within that project (and not the plug-in project) and now, the very same code works there!... It's strange but works...